# Future Function in dart return value

Tags: flutter, dart

What I am doing is I want to display the elevated button as either red or blue depending on the `boolean` value.

The boolean value will get its value from the function `getbool`. `getbool` compares an array in `Firebase` with a given string, if it exists, it returns true, else it returns false. I want to assign that returned value to a `boolean` variable so I can build the elevated button as either red or blue. But it throws this error:

```
A value of type 'Future<bool>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'bool'
```

I know state management or FutureBuilder can make it easy, but I am wondering why my code is not working as it is. I am using async and await in `getbool` method, and I cannot make the build method async to fix the problem either. so I am trying to do something impossible? would like to learn about this.

```
class CoursePage extends StatelessWidget {
  late String courseName;
  late Future<CourseModel> course = CourseModel.fromSnap(courseName);
  late Future<UserModel> profile = UserModel.fromId(AuthMethods().uid);
  //bool joinorExit = getbool(courseName, AuthMethods().uid);
  CoursePage({super.key, required this.courseName});
  late bool joinorExit;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  joinorExit = getbool(courseName, AuthMethods().uid);

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: course,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<CourseModel> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(snapshot.data!.Department),
                    joinorExit
                        ? ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                            onPressed: () => StudyGroupModel.CreateGroup(
                                courseName, AuthMethods().uid),
                            child: Text('join'))
                        : ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                            onPressed: () => StudyGroupModel.CreateGroup(
                                courseName, AuthMethods().uid),
                            child: Text('join')),
                    Text(snapshot.data!.Number),
                    Text(snapshot.data!.Name),
                    Text(snapshot.data!.Description),
                  ],
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const AlertDialog(title: Text("Error"));
              } else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }));
  }
}

Future<bool> getbool(String course, String id) async {
  bool joinExit = false;

  FirestoreService temp = FirestoreService.instance;
  if (await temp.documentExists(path: FirestorePath.studyGroupsspe(course))) {
    await temp.documentFuture(
        path: FirestorePath.studyGroupsspe(course),
        builder: (data) {
          if (data['members'].contains(id)) {
            joinExit = true;
            //setbool(joinExit);
          } else {
            joinExit = false;
            // setbool(joinExit);
          }
        });
  }
  return joinExit;
}
```

Comment: `getbool` must have the await key ex: `joinorExit = await getbool(courseName, AuthMethods().uid);` because its return is a future and without await it is not resolved, you are mixing async calls directly in the build, organizing this call in another futureBuilder would be the most appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you're trying to assign a `Future<bool>` to a `bool` variable directly. You can use another `FutureBuilder` to handle asynchronous operations and update the UI based on the result of `getbool` method.

```dart
class CoursePage extends StatelessWidget {
  late String courseName;
  late Future<CourseModel> course = CourseModel.fromSnap(courseName);
  late Future<UserModel> profile = UserModel.fromId(AuthMethods().uid);

  CoursePage({super.key, required this.courseName});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: course,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<CourseModel> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const AlertDialog(title: Text("Error"));
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return FutureBuilder(
              future: getbool(courseName, AuthMethods().uid),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> joinSnapshot) {
                if (joinSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                } else if (joinSnapshot.hasData) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(snapshot.data!.Department),
                      joinSnapshot.data!
                          ? ElevatedButton(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                              onPressed: () => StudyGroupModel.CreateGroup(
                                  courseName, AuthMethods().uid),
                              child: Text('join'))
                          : ElevatedButton(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                              onPressed: () => StudyGroupModel.CreateGroup(
                                  courseName, AuthMethods().uid),
                              child: Text('join')),
                      Text(snapshot.data!.Number),
                      Text(snapshot.data!.Name),
                      Text(snapshot.data!.Description),
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            );
          } else {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```